# Detect initialized variables

Tags: c++, initialization

Is there a way to check if certain variable is initialized before some point in a program?

For example, how to check if certain variable is initialized somewhere before the `IfStmt` node?
Methods from `VarDecl` class (`hasInit()` and `getInit()`) are not enough because of the following situation:

```
int x = 0; // hasInit() return true

int y;
...
y = 0; // initialized here, but hasInit() returns false
...
if (...) {}
```

Comment: what language are you using? the tags you've applied to the question relate to questions about compilers--your question is about the language. Is it C or is it C++? (Those are two very different languages).

Comment: It is C++ programming language.

Comment: `y = 0; // initialized here` This is not initialization. This is assignment. Initialization can only be done as a part of variable declaration (i.e. `int y = 0;`).

Answer (score 1):

If you maintain a product written by C++ code and hope to remove ugly indeterminate variables, a reasonable way to do it is defining an initializing function or lambda `f`, and then declare a local variable as `const auto x = f(...);` from the get-go.

OTOH, if you delay the value asignment **on purpose**, there are several methods to detect the value is assigned or not.
I just came up with following methods.

---

**std::optional**

In C++17 and over,
`std::optional<T>` enables us to detect whether values are assigned or not.
`std::optional::has_value` and `std::optional::value` correspond to your `hasInit` and `getInit` respectively as follows:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/95rHGn9GRsFJBi7q)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

template<typename T>
void checkInitialization(const std::optional<T>& a)
{
    if(a.has_value()){            
        std::cout << "Value is assigned by " << a.value() << "." << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Value is still not assigned." << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    std::optional<int> x;

    checkInitialization(x); // Value is still not assigned
    
    x = 1;
    checkInitialization(x); // Value is assigned

    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

> Value is still not assigned.
>
> Value is assigned by 1.

---

**std::unique_ptr**

We can also check it using `std::unique_ptr<T>` which is introduced from C++11.
First we define a variable as `std::unique_ptr<T> x;` where `(x == nullptr)` is still true.
Later on, we assign a value by `x = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(1))` and then `(x == nullptr)` becomes false.
(In C++14 `x = std::make_unique<int>(1)` works and is simple.)
Thus we can again get the previous output with the following code:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rMZrF94ksgKM86LR)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
bool hasInit(const std::unique_ptr<T>& a)
{
    return (a != nullptr);
}

template<typename T>
const T& getInit(const std::unique_ptr<T>& a)
{
    return *a;
}

template<typename T>
void checkInitialization(const std::unique_ptr<T>& a)
{
    if(hasInit(a)){   
        std::cout << "Value is assigned by " << getInit(a) << "." << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Value is still not assigned." << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> x;

    checkInitialization(x); // Uninitialized
    
    x = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(1));
    //x = std::make_unique<int>(1); // C++14
    checkInitialization(x); // Initialized

    return 0;
}
```

---

**std::pair**

We can also apply `std::pair<bool, T>` where `std::pair::first` and `std::pair::second` correspond to your `hasInit` and `getInit` respectively.
We again get the previous output:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hMDttB2K8SJgJkZW)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
void checkInitialization(const std::pair<bool, T>& a)
{
    if(a.first){   
        std::cout << "Value is assigned by " << a.second << "." << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Value is still not assigned." << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    std::pair<bool, int> x{false, 0};

    checkInitialization(x); // Uninitialized
    
    x = {true, 1};
    checkInitialization(x); // Initialized

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly as mentioned in the comments:

```
int y = 0; // initialization
int y; y = 0; // assignment
```

Let's assume you want to detect assignment. One simple way could be wrap the integer you want to track in a struct and write a custom `operator = (int)`. For example:

```
struct Foo 
{
   Foo() {std::cout << "default init" << std::endl;} 
   Foo& operator = (int elem) 
   { 
      cout<<"Int-Assignment operator called "<<endl;
      x = elem;
      is_assigned = true;
      return *this;
   }
   int x = 0; // default initialized to 0
   bool is_assigned = false; // default initialized to false
};
```

Now let's see what happens:

```
int main() 
{ 
  Foo t1; 
  // t1.is_assigned is false
  t1 = 0; 
  // t1.is_assigned is true
  return 0; 
}
```

You could use something like this or a variant if needed. Here's the [code running online](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fd1d860710eaedb) corresponding to the above.

Is this what you wanted?